# Buffered image being read but not appearing

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm new to graphics in java and have been trying to get it nailed down but I've been stuck on this problem for the last two weeks.

There are two classes, one which reads files(which I think is working properly) and one that displays them. (I think that's where the problem stands)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class jpaneTesting extends JFrame implements Runnable
{

    public jpaneTesting(int x, int y)
    {
        super("testing");
        this.setBounds( 0, 0, x, y );
        this.setVisible( true );
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        loader loader = new loader();
        BufferedImage character = loader.load("src\\resources\\hey.png"); //accesses hey.png
        g2.drawImage(character,null,5,5);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread (new jpaneTesting(500,500));
        thread.start(); //runs the thread that was sent that argument
    }
}


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class loader {

    public BufferedImage load(String path){
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            return img;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("oh no!"); //testing if image actually got there for myself
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2):

So many problems here:

- You're trying to draw directly within a JFrame, something you should avoid doing as the JFrame paint is responsible for so much, and overriding it without need courts trouble.
- Instead do as the tutorials point out: draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, and place that JPanel in your JFrame.
- Also do as the tutorials point out: call the super painting method within your override.
- You're reading in an image from within a painting method, again a bad thing to do, one that needlessly reads in the image multiple times, and needlessly slows down painting.
- Read the image in **once**, before displaying the GUI if possible, and place into a field. Then draw it in your paintComponent method after checking for null.
- Your `g.drawImage(...)` method is incorrect with null in the wrong place. Avoid using null and instead place `this` into the last parameter.
- Your use of threading is suspect. At least queue your GUI code on the Swing event thread.
- Again, I can't repeat enough: read the tutorials on this as there's nothing new under the sun. Learn from the experts.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowingImage extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage myImage; // variable to hold reference to image

    public ShowingImage(BufferedImage img) {
        this.myImage = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // first call super method to do "house-keeping" drawing 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (myImage != null) {
            // if the image isn't null, draw it
            g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    // size our GUI based on the image size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || myImage == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = myImage.getWidth();
        int h = myImage.getHeight();
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui(BufferedImage img) {
        ShowingImage mainPanel = new ShowingImage(img);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowingImage");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // the image path below must contain a path to image file relative to the class files location
        String imagePath = "";  // TODO: fix this with real path!

        URL imageUrl = ShowingImage.class.getResource(imagePath);
        try {
            final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);

            // start GUI on the Swing event thread
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please check out the comments in the code. The code above is not complete, and will not work until you change the line `String imagePath = "";` so that it holds a String that points to an image path *relative to the path to your class files*. You will probably want to create a subdirectory off of one of your class package directories, and perhaps call it images, and place the application's images there.